# adding page numbers and creating landscape A4 in streams with itext

Tags: itext

I have the following code that generates a pdf into the stream. This works well but i now have the following requirements.

1) make page landscape: Looking at other examples they add the property to the document object. But i'm doing this instream. So how would i add this property?

2) Add page numbers.   I need to put items into a grid so that there are x number of rows per page. With a page number at the footer of the page. How can this kind of feature be acheived with Itext sharp.

```
public static void Create(ICollection<Part> parts, string path)
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);

    var pageWidth = 500;
    byte[] bytes;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms))
        {
            PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(1);

                  //Flush the PdfStamper's buffer
            stamper.Close();
            //Get the raw bytes of the PDF
            bytes = ms.ToArray();
            var now = String.Format("{0:d-M-yyyy}", DateTime.Now);
            var pdfName = string.Format("{0}_factory_worksheet", now).Replace("%", "").Replace(" ", "_");

            var context = HttpContext.Current;
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + pdfName);
            context.Response.Buffer = true;
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);
            context.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
            context.Response.End();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So you're not generating a PDF from scratch, you're actually taking parts from an existing one, right?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know how you handling it C# but logical flow will be like this:
Use **PdfDictionary**  to rotate content in reader to 90 degree.Assuming your pdf contain multiple pages,
**PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);

for (int pgCnt=1; pgCnt <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); pgCnt++) {

           //Logic to implement rotation & Add Page number

}**
To get current rotation(assuming you are using Portrait mode & try to convert it in landscape mode) use 
**int rttnPg = reader.getPageRotation(pgCnt);**
 also get the PdfDictionary of that page 
**pgDctnry=reader.getPageN(i);**(I named that variable as pgDctnry)
Now to rotate it in 90 degree use 
**pgDctnry.put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(rttnPg+90));**
Now bind it using PdfStamper as you are currently doing it.Now to add page number get over content(here i named it pgCntntBt) of the current page 
**pgCntntBt = stamper .getOverContent(pgCnt);

rctPgSz = rdrPgr.getPageSizeWithRotation(pgCnt);

pgCntntBt.beginText();

bfUsed=//Base Font used for text to be displayed.Also set font size 
pgCntntBt.setFontAndSize(bfUsed,8.2f);
txtPg=String.format(pgTxt+" %d/%d",pgCnt,totPgCnt);

pgCntntBt.showTextAligned(2,txtPg,//Put Width,//Put Height,//Rotation);

pgCntntBt.endText();**
Actually i don't understand  what you mean by this:**"I need to put items into a grid so that there are x number of rows per page. With a page number at the footer of the page"**.Now close the stamper to flush it in outputstream.